# Why a window procedure is called before polling for an event?

Tags: winapi

During debugging [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/your-first-windows-program) example I have noticed that `WindowProc` is called right after `CreateWindowEx`. The first message is `WM_GETMINMAXINFO`. I have thought that `WindowProc` will be called first time after calling `DispatchMessage` from the message loop:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

It's not intuitive for me. Could please explain why does it work this way ? Is it possible to get all events only from the message loop ?

Comment: There are many messages that have to be elaborated on creation of the window dispatched from system directly. I.e. WM_CREATE. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create

Comment: *"Is it possible to get all events only from the message loop ?"* - No. The message queue is only concerned with queued messages. [About Messages and Message Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues) covers this in great detail.

Comment: I can't really understand why this is troublesome for you. Why do you care about the window proc being called in this way?

Comment: Each loop checks for events in the message queue. If there is, take out the first event and execute it. After executing one, enter the next loop. If not, it goes into hibernation.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT That doesn't add anything useful in the context of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the message is not sent after the `CreateWindowEx()`. It is sent from that function. The point is that (most) messages sent from the same thread are synchronously, i.e. instead of inserting the message into the message queue, the target window procedure is called directly as an ordinary function. (See documentation of `SendMessage()` for more info about this.)

If you think of it, it often times makes good sense: For example the window procedure needs to process `WM_NCCREATE` or `WM_CREATE` before the `CreateWindowEx()` returns so that the caller gets fully created window which is some meaningful initialized state.

As a side note, it's unfortunate that Windows sends `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` before `WM_NCCREATE` for any top-level window so handling this message may require some special care as internal window's state is not likely yet initialized.